# TinyMCE - Select text, alter text, update the editor and restore the selection

Tags: javascript, html, tinymce, range, wysiwyg

I am working on a plugin for TinyMCE. The process should be like this:

1) The user selects some text

2) He presses a toolbar button of my custom plugin

3) A custom function is executed that does a custom action on the selected text, for example, lets say it surrounds the selected text with underline tags: `<u></u>`

4) After doing the action, the selected text is then inserted back inside the editor where the selection was made

5) Now, regardless of the selected text, I take ALL the editor's HTML and alter it according to my needs, such as adding a custom attribute to each tag in the HTML

6) Having the new HTML I want to insert it back into the editor

7) Moreover, the selected text should be still highlighted at the end of the process

**I am struggling with steps 4-7.**

My problems are divided in 2 steps:

A) I get the selected text and I can change it. The problem is I do not know how to set it back to the entire editor's text. In the plugin I do:

```
var newSelectionHTML = ed.selection.getContent();
```

But how can I update the selected part of the editor's text with newSelectionHTML

B) I do not know how to alter the whole editor's HTML and set it into the editor, while maintaining the user selection.

```
ed.setContent(newHTML)
```

Doing this removes the user selection and moves the cursor to the beginning. How can I save the user selection through the whole process (steps 1-7)?

Thank you in advance.
Asaf

Comment: I'm doing something similar but I'm unable to iterate all the selected nodes in the range. Did you find a way to do that because the selection in TinyMCE doesn't have the function [containsNode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Selection/containsNode) for some reason

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@jnoreiga's answer was very nearly the solution for me. Since tinymce seems to expecting an object with type Range it won't accept your plain object `originalRange`

I simply had to call `getRng` again, store that to a new variable and set that variable's properties with `originalRange` properties

```
var originalRange = jQuery.extend(true, {}, editor.selection.getRng());

/*
 * Do some logic,
 * Then set current range to originalRange
 */

var newRange = editor.selection.getRng();

newRange.startContainer = originalRange.startContainer;
newRange.startOffset = originalRange.startOffset;
newRange.startContainer = originalRange.endContainer;
newRange.startOffset = originalRange.endOffset;

editor.selection.setRng(newRange);
```

Answer (score 1):

store your range using cloning when the dialog first opens

```
originalRange = jQuery.extend(true, {}, editor.selection.getRng());
```

Then when you want to go back to the original selection

```
editor.selection.setRng(originalRange);
```

Comment: This was very nearly the solution for me. Since tinymce seems to expecting an object with type Range it won't accept your plain object `originalRange`

I simply had to call `getRng` again, store that to a new variable and set that variable's properties with `originalRange` properties

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `jQuery.extend`, just call the range's `cloneRange` method. The resulting range can be used directly in `setRng`.